# Vocal sheet music with right-to-left languages

Tags: sheet-music

How would sheet music be written for vocals in a right-to-left language (Hebrew or Arabic)? It seems there would be a clash between the left-to-right convention of sheet music and the right-to-left of the language.

Comment: @JacobSwanson: Ah, but surely those Yiddish versions of my favourite Lieder _do_?

Answer (score 6):

One possibility that is seen in Hebrew occasionally is to print a mirrored score (including all symbols) apart from the lyrics.  Most of the time, however, you just get the score straight, and the lyrics left-to-right, syllable by right-to-left syllable.  I would imagine that it takes some practice singing that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you show an example? I looked for one and couldn't find any.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an image of a hymnal in St. George's Cathedral, Jerusalem.
It shows Western music notation, written right-to-left, with the clefs and key sig on the right hand side, and a well-known hymn tune (Forest Green).

[image]

Comment: I see the music symbols are written in a right-to-left order, but the symbols themselves aren't mirrored. Interesting

Comment: Reversed sheet music is surprisingly easy to read to me, at least compared to reversed english text (txet hsilgne desrever).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen many examples, but on [this Persian web site](http://www.khaneyeparastesh.com/%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%87%D8%A7), they use Roman letters for the words in the [sheet music](https://khaneyeparastesh.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/songs/music_sheet/6-Dar_Hozoore_to.pdf):

[image: song with words in Roman script]

Note that most of the web site uses Persian (Arabic-based) script, including the [pages](https://khaneyeparastesh.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/songs/lyrics/6-Dar_Hozoore_to.pdf) that show the words of songs without the melody:

[image: song with words in Persian script]

So the roman letters above are an exception, presumably used for the purpose of fitting into the left-to-right musical notation.